# How to render different partial for different type of an object belongs to other object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm built app which allow users create questions are type: True/False, Single and Multiple Choice. So, I have created some models:

```
class QuestionType < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :shorcut
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :mark, :topic_id, :question_type_id, :answers_attributes
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question_type
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :question_id, :correct

  belongs_to :question
end
```

Now i would to build an index page of questions, have 3 link to add question for 3 type of question, when users click a link, they will go to page to create question and page will have appropriate form for type of that question. In Question controller, i want to store question type id to save to question.
I think the addresses like this:

http://example.com/questions/index : Index page will have 3 link to create question.

http://example.com/question_types/1/questions/new: Will render partial form for True/False question

http://example.com/question_types/2/questions/new: Will render partial form for Single choice question

http://example.com/question_types/1/questions/new: Will render partial form for Multiple choice question

I think i have to put nested resources in my routes with question type and question model to have above type of link, but i don't know how to build view and separate like above. please help me or give me an idea, better way to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my understanding of your question, this might solve your question:

in your app/views/questions/new.html.erb you can do it like this:

```
    case params[:question_type_id]
    when 1
    render :partial=>"/questions/new_true_false_question"
    when 2
    render :partial=>"/questions/new_single"
    when 3
    render :partial=>"/questions/new_multi"
    end
```

and then create the three partials as refered abow or in whatever names you like.

OR you can do it in the controller by chaning render :partial to render :template.

:)

Comment: if you did it correct in the nesting routes, this params[:question_type_id] will contain the question type's id you set in the link. ie for the link http://example.com/question_types/1/questions/new, the value of this param will be 1.